# How can I give margin to ::marker?

Tags: html, css

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: '-';
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>Mapping of Product</li>
</ul>
```

This is my code. After this, I get markers like it's shown in the image below

[image]

So I want to have a margin between "-" and text, but the margin does not work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not a margin between the `list-style-type` and the `text`. It is the `padding-left` that controls it.

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: '-';
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Mapping of Product</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Doesn't work with the default marker.

Comment: In order to make this way work you have to check that the parent <ul> doesn't have the style `list-style-position: inside`

Answer (score 1):

Just include a space after the `-` (within the quotes):

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: '- ';
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>Mapping of Product</li>
   <li>Mapping of Product</li>
   <li>Mapping of Product</li>
</ul>
```